# How to support airplay in the background in iOS6

Tags: video, background, ios6, airplay

My app should stream video's to an AppleTV via Airplay, even when the app is in the background.

Under iOS5 it worked perfectly. In iOS6 it does not.

Xcode gives me a deprecated warning on this line of code:

```
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Is this the reason why my app isn't functioning correctly anymore. What is the equivalent of this piece of code in iOS6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution: this problem can be solved by setting the right AVAudioSessionCategory

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
```

Comment: @Murze here what is AVAudioSession ??

Comment: @iPatel: `#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Besides @murze's solution you should also set value `App plays audio` for `Required background modes` key in infoPlist file like @ACBurk suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8807958/384864