# How to let a video, that is streamed via AirPlay not pause, when the screen is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, airplay

I use both, a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and a `MPMoviePlayerController` to play back videos in my app. I also allow the use of AirPlay to stream these videos on to an Apple TV.

This all works fine. The only problem is, that the streamed video pauses, when the screen gets locked.

I noticed, that a lot of apps support this, but I don't know how to achive this feature.

I tried to set:

```
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

But that didn't work on either iOS 5 or iOS 6 so I tried using :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

But that didn't even compile.

Both ways are discussed here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814574/how-to-support-airplay-in-the-background-in-ios6`

What can I do? Or what do I do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Andreas

Comment: Try putting in your Info.plist under "Required background modes" add "App plays audio"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823268/1219698) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814574/how-to-support-airplay-in-the-background-in-ios6) should help you, I've had the same problem in one of my apps and these helped. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well thanks! That solved it. I should have imported the AVFoundation.framework into my project. The problem was sitting 40cm from the screen away in this case ;-)